# what is the best practice to store the locators at one common location for protractor?

Tags: protractor

I could not find a good example showing the correct or effective way to store the locators for easy organization/modification. Can someone point me to one?
Preferably a config file or another .js file.

Again an example will greatly help.

Thanks!

Comment: for example [page objects](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md)?

Answer (score 1):

The "best practice" is to put your locators in a page object.

example: https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/website/test/e2e

Docs: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/page-objects

Answer (score 0):

I'll second the use of page objects and have some [additional examples on GitHub](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example)...